# Declaring a new function vs calling it right away?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried googling for the answer but the problem is I don't really know how to address the problem, i just find the wrong topics.

What's the difference between:

```
this.on('click',thisismyfunction );
```

and:

```
this.on('click', function(){

thisismyfunction();

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One notable difference: the first function will be directly passed an event object, accessible by whatever you name the first argument of `thisismyfunction`, or at `arguments[0]`. In the second version, that object will be passed to the outer anonymous function.

Also, on both examples *nothing* is called right away. You're binding both functions (your named function in the first case, or the anonymous function in the second case) as event handlers, so they will be invoked after the related event occurs.

Which one you use will depend mostly on code structure and style. As bennett_an said, it's preferable to use the first variation when you're binding the same function to multiple events.

Comment: So technically, I would use an anonymous function if i need to send arguments right?

Comment: No, you get the arguments on whatever function you pass to `.on()`, named or not. But if you use an anonymous function an call another function from there, this other function won't get the event object unless you explicitly pass them ahead.

Answer (score 2):

One is a named function. The point of that is that you may be calling the function from multiple places, multiple times.
The other is an annonomous function. It basically is like saying  "do the following:"

> Functions: A function in JavaScript can be either named or anonymous.
>   A named function can be defined using function keyword as follows:
>
> ```
> function named(){
>    // do some stuff here
> }
> ```
>
> An anonymous function can
>   be defined in similar way as a normal function but it would not have
>   any name.
>
> A anonymous function can be assigned to a variable or passed to a
>   method as shown below.
>
> ```
> var handler = function (){
>    // do some stuff here 
> }
> ```
>
> JQuery makes a
>   use of anonymous functions very frequently as follows:
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>    // do some stuff here 
> });
> ```

As taken from [TutorialsPoint jQuery Basics](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-basics.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Really nothing.

The first example will bind to `thisismyfunction` directly.  The second example will bind to an anonymous function that then calls `thisismyfunction()` when called.

Answer (score 0):

thisismyfunction will recieve no arguments. the way you have it embed in the anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

In your example there is probably no difference to the outcome. But the two methods do behave slightly differently:

First example:

- `this` inside your function refers to the clicked on element
- the event object will be passed to the element via its parameters

Second Example

- `this` inside your function refers to the anonymous function
- you can easily pass your own arguments, or none at all in this case
- you can attach multiple function calls to the same event

So which style you use depends on your own preferences and what you want to achieve